# How to load a Gameobject in Unity from a server maintaining its components and properties?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, unity-networking

I'm working on a `GameObject` in Unity, what i want is that the `GameObject` should download from a server link maintaining all its references and components so that it should perform the way it is performing offline.
The purpose of doing is that i want to reduce the application size hence giving user an option to whether download the gameobject or not.

Comment: you're just looking for asset bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html), which will allow you to safe a gameobject with all references.

> Unity has a Prefab asset type that allows you to store a GameObject object complete with components and properties. The prefab acts as a template from which you can create new object instances in the scene. Any edits made to a prefab asset are immediately reflected in all instances produced from it but you can also override components and settings for each instance individually.

These prefabs can be provided in [AssetBundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) from your server to easily re-integrate into your game

> AssetBundles have been designed to simplify downloading content to your application. They can contain any kind of Asset type recognized by Unity, as determined by the filename extension. If you want to include files with custom binary data, they should have the extension “.bytes”. Unity will import these files as TextAssets.

Comment: Thanks @MX D but when i create a prefab of that gameobject it does not hold the grandchildren but only children

Comment: @Learner13 [That is intended behaviour](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/showing-deeper-nested-levels-in-prefabs-project-view.8101/). All though as MatthewW mentions on the link provided. `Double-clicking a prefab brings to you to a scene view with just that prefab instantiated in the scene hierarchy. So you can see the prefab in 3D, edit whatever you need to, and then when you close out of this view it goes back to whatever level you were previously editing`

Comment: See i have a gameobject which further have children and grandchildren to which many scripts and values are attached. Now what i want is that to remove this Gameobject model from application build and allow user to download it which contains all its features.... so with this will be maintained as cache...... i looked in Assetbundles on how to create and load but as far are as scripts and their values are concerned i am not able to do so.....so it would be a great help if you just guide me with the process....thanks @MX D